# Django form based view GET response

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

To create a form on the website homepage I created a form class and a request class. 
Somehow I am not able to get the response into the url querystring.

Could someone help me with this one?

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CurrencyConverterForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            base_currency = form.data.__getitem__('base_currency')
            counter_currency = form.data.__getitem__('counter_currency')
            base_amount = form.data.__getitem__('base_amount')

        counter_amount = get_conversion_amount(base_currency, counter_currency, datetime.now(), base_amount)

        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        response['base_currency'] = base_currency
        response['counter_currency'] = counter_currency
        response['base_amount'] = base_amount

        return response
else:
    form = CurrencyConverterForm()

context = {'form': form}

return render(request, '../templates/client/index.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class CurrencyConverterForm(forms.Form):
    base_currency = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Currency.objects.all(), required=True)
    counter_currency = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Currency.objects.all(), required=True)
    base_amount = forms.FloatField(required=True)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

index.html

```
<form action="" method="get">
    {{ form.as_ul }}
    <input type="submit" value="Convert"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Setting attributes on the response sets header fields. Is that what you want?

Comment: You don't need `form.data.__getitem__`, you can access cleaned data like `form.cleaned_data['base_currency']`.

Comment: More generally, you *never* need to call the double-underscore methods directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access form data in like this:

```
data = form.cleaned_data['data']
```

So your view has to look like:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CurrencyConverterForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            base_currency = form.cleaned_data['base_currency']
            counter_currency = form.cleaned_data['counter_currency']
            base_amount = form.cleaned_data['base_amount']

        counter_amount = get_conversion_amount(base_currency, counter_currency, datetime.now(), base_amount)

        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        response['base_currency'] = base_currency
        response['counter_currency'] = counter_currency
        response['base_amount'] = base_amount

        return response
else:
    form = CurrencyConverterForm()

context = {'form': form}

return render(request, '../templates/client/index.html', context)
```

Comment: @ pythad Thanks for your help so far. However when I hit the submit button now, the query string and the fields are all empty. How could I be able to solve these?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve it.

I actually needed a lot less code then I expected.

```
def index(request):
    counter_amount = ""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CurrencyConverterForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_base_currency = form.cleaned_data['form_base_currency']
            form_counter_currency = form.cleaned_data['form_counter_currency']
            form_base_amount = form.cleaned_data['form_base_amount']

            # Calculate the counter_amount
            counter_amount = get_conversion_amount(form_base_currency, form_counter_currency, datetime.now(),
                                                   form_base_amount)
            # Retrieve the counter amount from the dict
            counter_amount = counter_amount['GetConversionAmountResult']
            # Maximize the number of decimals to 4
            if counter_amount.as_tuple().exponent < -4:
                counter_amount = "%.4f" % counter_amount

    else:
        form = CurrencyConverterForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'counter_amount': counter_amount
    }

    return render(request, '../templates/client/index.html', context)
```